# How to interpret the code structure of product-am

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I got wso2am4.0.0 source code from github, which composed of some modules, hut i don't know how to interpret  the structure and how to run or debug in ide, can anyone guide me how to do that?

Comment: You can refer to this document[1] to be aware of the debugging process. [1]. https://anuradha-15.medium.com/remote-debugging-wso2-products-using-intellij-idea-ide-c0e828abd700

Answer (score 1):

WSO2AM consists of several components and those components are bundled together. This bundling logic is implemented at [product apim](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v4.0.0). All the major components of APIM are implemented at a [separate repo](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v9.0.174) and you can find the java code for its backend functionalities and the UI components there. Each of these components has its own versions and the parallel `carbon-apimgt` version for `APIM 4.0.0` is `v9.0.174`. There are several other component repos and you can find those from the artifact ID in each imported dependency find [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v9.0.174/pom.xml).